# css animations that have not finished glitch out ui

Tags: css, css-transitions

**Question**:
can css detect the if an animation is incomplete?

---

**storytime**:
I have a cool ui with animated buttons. they grow if you hover over them. therefore the other buttons in the button bar should shrink at the same time.

---

**My problem** (*specific to this but also general because I've had this problem in more than one case.*):
when I go over all of the buttons to fast 2 buttons are shrinking and only 1 button is growing and thus they do not fill up the button bar like they should.

---

**code with error:**

```
.container:hover button{
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 5%);
}
.container button:hover{
    width: calc((100% / 3) + 10%);
}
```

---

**Full code:**

```css
.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container button {
  transition: .15s;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.container:hover button {
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 5%);
}

.container button:hover {
  width: calc((100% / 3) + 10%);
}

button.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

button.blue {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
}

button.white {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

body {
  background-color: #929AAA;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: calc(100vh / 4 - 50px) auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="white">to site</button>
  <button class="blue">login</button>
  <button class="green">register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: first you have a specifity issue, it should be `.container button:hover` to see the effect

Comment: sorry, tried to simplify the code and thereby broke it xD fixed in post and CP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea is to make only one element changing its size and the other will shrink. Here is an example with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  transition: .15s;
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
}
/* you want to have 28% + 44% + 28% so it's 1 + 1.57 + 1*/
.container button:hover {
  flex: 1.57;
}

/*For styling*/
button.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}

button.blue {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
}

button.white {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

body {
  background-color: #929AAA;
}

div.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: calc((100vh - 100px) / 2) auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="white">to site</button>
  <button class="blue">login</button>
  <button class="green">register</button>
</div>
```